# What happens during the task transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug? And when can duplicate classes can cause dex failure?

Tags: android, gradle, dex

In few cases when I include duplicate classes (with same java package name) as part of different jars then I'm getting this error

```
> Task :transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
```

but this is not happening always. Sometimes I'm hitting this hard road and sometimes not. I would like to get clarity on this issue to understand it and avoid it further.

When can I expect this failure? Is that only during when the class files come under same dex something like that?

**EDIT**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
 at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeMultidex(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:266)
 at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:133)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
 at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
 at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
 ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
 at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
 at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/learn/android/candycrush/Origamy$OrigamyCallback;
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:660)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:615)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:597)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:197)
 at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
```

Comment: Generally this error is being accompanied with a more detailed description of what happened. Do you see any errors/warnings above?

Comment: @AlexLipov : Sorry I missed the exact tract. But i remember this error message was followed by the reason with "Caused by: XYZ class duplication" something like that.. But before the start of this task i do not remember seeing something.

Comment: The class duplication can indeed be the root cause for this error. It generally happens when two (or more) libraries you're compiling with include a class having the same name. I'd suggest you to include the exact "Caused by..." error message next time you encounter it.

Comment: Sure i'll try to reproduce it and add it here @AlexLipov.

Comment: @AlexLipov : The reason that i could find from the above trace is that my class OrigamyCallback is included multiple times (from multiple jars). But this is not always happening to me. Sometimes i face this dex merge failure and sometimes not which is confusing for me. I would like to understand the actual cause for this issue. How can i get to know that?